# How to style the width and height of the individual images in Nivo slider?

Tags: jquery, nivo-slider

I'm using some images which I want to have NO width or height. In other words, I want to remove the auto generated CSS attribute that is given to each image in the slider, because the inclusion of "width" and "height" in the DOM on the page makes the image look pixelated for some reason.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing CSS, it is better to display images like this:
1) If image size is larger than the screen size (image viewer size), you may display it as you wish.
2) But, if image size is less than the screen size (image viewer size), display it in actual size.